# Hibernate Criteria Left Joining Two Tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria, left-join

I have two entities, say Business and Area.

Relevant properties:
Business - area, area2, code
Area - areaId, areaName

area and area2 of Business map to the id in Area

I'm trying to write a Hibernate criteria that returns all the areas with businesses only.

SQL looks like:
FROM area a LEFT OUTER JOIN business b on a.areaId = b.area or a.areaId = b.area2
WHERE b.code != null
GROUP BY a.areaName

This is what I have:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Business.class)
.setProjection(Property.forName("area"))
.setProjection(Property.forName("area2"))
.add(Restrictions.ne("code", null));

Criteria criteriaArea = fullTextSession.createCriteria(Area.class)
.createAlias("areaId", "areaId", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
.add(Property.forName("areaId").in(criteria));
```

But this doesn't work, I get a "not an association: areaId" query exception.

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Small tip: use Restrictions.isNotNull("code"). In some databases "<> null" differs from "is not null".

Comment: Did you put relation into entity definition?(xml or annotations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`createAlias()` joins another entity using provided property. Hibernate calculates what table to join using mapping of provided property. But `areaId` isn't mapped as a `@ManyToOne` or `@ManyToMany` reference to Business entity. So Hibernate doesn't understand to what table you want to join using Area.areaId.

Your criteria will be translated to SQL like:

```
select a.* from Area a
left join <here should be table referenced by areaId> b on a.areaId = b.id
where a.areaId in (
  select area, area2 from Business where code <> null
)
```

You may rewrite query without unused join:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria1 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Business.class)
.setProjection(Property.forName("area"));

DetachedCriteria criteria2 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Business.class)
.setProjection(Property.forName("area2"));

Criteria criteriaArea = fullTextSession.createCriteria(Area.class)
.add(Restrictions.or(
  Property.forName("areaId").in(criteria1),
  Property.forName("areaId").in(criteria2)
);
```